# Where should I load database values in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to download data from my DB before my home screen loads, I currently am calling that function in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` in my `AppDelegate.Swift` file, but that function does not get called before my Home screen's `viewDidLoad()` function, where is the fastest place to download database data in iOS?

Comment: "I want to download data from my DB before the app launches" doesn't quite make sense, does it?  But try it with `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

Comment: that indeed does not make sense, updated with a better explanation. Thank you for your  help!

Comment: It loads it just as quickly as ```didFinishLaunching```

Comment: Assuming that your database download is coming over the network and therefore completes asynchronously, you can't (and don't want to) download it before your home screen loads; This would give the impression that your app has hung and if you take too long then the watchdog will kill your app.  Your home screen should display some message or activity indicator if the data isn't yet loaded and you refresh it when the data is available

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work as I have not seen your code. If you are using Storyboard you can use the `ViewWillLoad` function. Swift UI only has a `ViewDidLoad` and no `ViewWillLoad` function to my knowledge; The best place in a SwiftUI application would be in your `SceneDelegate` in the `func scene(...)` right before `let contentView = ContentView()`. Here you can load your data and store it. This will allow you to load the data before anything is presented. This might cause the user to wait longer than usual for your data to load so you shouldn't ignore your `LaunchScreen`.